# Какой нужен знак препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение такого типа: "Я его спросил(,) как пройти в библиотеку". После слова спросил лучше ставить запятую или двоеточие? И нужен ли на конце вопросительный знак?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Знаки Вы поставили правильно: нужна запятая, а не двоеточие. Вопросительный знак не нужен, так как вторая часть сложноподчинённого предложения присоединяется относительным словом как и вопросительная интонация исчезает. Вы преобразовали прямую речь в косвенную с помощью сложноподчинённого предложения с придаточным изъяснительным.